# How do i access the destination file directory from javascript?

Tags: javascript, mirth, mirth-connect

In the javascript transformer i could access the Source Directory given in the Source Tab of mirth by

```
var xmlDirectoryName = sourceMap.get("fileDirectory");
```

likewise how do i access the destination file directory from javascript?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a 3.X version, you can iterate through your channel's destination properties to find the one you want based off the name and get the "Host" property of that destination.

```
var CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL ID";
var DESTINATION_NAME = "DESTINATION NAME"
var destinationDirectory = "";

for each (destination in com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.DefaultChannelController.create().getDeployedChannelById(CHANNEL_ID).getDestinationConnectors().toArray()) {
    if (destination.getName() == DESTINATION_NAME) {
        destinationDirectory = destination.getProperties().getHost();
        break;
    }
}
```